# Merge multiple dataframes with non-unique indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of pandas time series.  Here is an example for illustration (real data has ~ 1 million entries in each series):

```
>>> for s in series:
    print s.head()
    print
2014-01-01 01:00:00   -0.546404
2014-01-01 01:00:00   -0.791217
2014-01-01 01:00:01    0.117944
2014-01-01 01:00:01   -1.033161
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.013415
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.368853
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.380515
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.976505
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.881654
dtype: float64

2014-01-01 01:00:00   -0.111314
2014-01-01 01:00:01    0.792093
2014-01-01 01:00:01   -1.367650
2014-01-01 01:00:02   -0.469194
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.569606
2014-01-01 01:00:02   -1.777805
dtype: float64

2014-01-01 01:00:00   -0.108123
2014-01-01 01:00:00   -1.518526
2014-01-01 01:00:00   -1.395465
2014-01-01 01:00:01    0.045677
2014-01-01 01:00:01    1.614789
2014-01-01 01:00:01    1.141460
2014-01-01 01:00:02    1.365290
dtype: float64
```

The times in each series are not unique.  For example, the last series has 3 values at `2014-01-01 01:00:00`.  The second series has only one value at that time.  *Also, not all the times need to be present in all the series*.

My goal is to create a merged `DataFrame` with times that are a union of all the times in the individual time series.  Each timestamp should be repeated as many times as needed.  So, if a timestamp occurs `(2, 0, 3, 4)` times in the series above, the timestamp should be repeated 4 times (the maximum of the frequencies) in the resulting `DataFrame`.  The values of each column should be "filled forward".

As an example, the result of merging the above should be:

```
                             c0                c1              c2
2014-01-01 01:00:00   -0.546404         -0.111314       -0.108123
2014-01-01 01:00:00   -0.791217         -0.111314       -1.518526
2014-01-01 01:00:00   -0.791217         -0.111314       -1.395465
2014-01-01 01:00:01    0.117944          0.792093        0.045677
2014-01-01 01:00:01   -1.033161         -1.367650        1.614789
2014-01-01 01:00:01   -1.033161         -1.367650        1.141460
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.013415         -0.469194        1.365290
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.368853          0.569606        1.365290
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.380515         -1.777805        1.365290
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.976505         -1.777805        1.365290
2014-01-01 01:00:02    0.881654         -1.777805        1.365290
```

To give an idea of size and "uniqueness" in my real data:

```
>>> [len(s.index.unique()) for s in series]
[48617, 48635, 48720, 48620]
>>> len(times)
51043
>>> [len(s) for s in series]
[1143409, 1143758, 1233646, 1242864]
```

Here is what I have tried:

I can create a union of all the unique times:

```
uniques = [s.index.unique() for s in series]
times = uniques[0].union_many(uniques[1:])
```

I can now index each series using `times`:

```
series[0].loc[times]
```

But that seems to repeat the values for each item in `times`, which is not what I want.

I can't `reindex()` the series using `times` because the index for each series is not unique.

I can do it by a slow Python loop or do it in Cython, but is there a "pandas-only" way to do what I want to do?

I created my example series using the following code:

```
def make_series(n=3, rep=(0,5)):
    times = pandas.date_range('2014/01/01 01:00:00', periods=n, freq='S')
    reps = [random.randint(*rep) for _ in xrange(n)]
    dates = []
    values = numpy.random.randn(numpy.sum(reps))
    for date, rep in zip(times, reps):
        dates.extend([date]*rep)
    return pandas.Series(data=values, index=dates)

series = [make_series() for _ in xrange(3)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *very* nearly a concat:

```
In [11]: s0 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], name='s0')

In [12]: s1 = pd.Series([1, 4, 5], name='s1')

In [13]: pd.concat([s0, s1], axis=1)
Out[13]:
   s0  s1
0   1   1
1   2   4
2   3   5
```

**However**, concat cannot deal with duplicate indices (it's ambigious how they should merge, and in your case you don't want to merge them in the "ordinary" way - as combinations)...

I think you are going to use a groupby:

```
In [21]: s0 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1], name='s0')

In [22]: s1 = pd.Series([1, 4, 5], [0, 1, 1], name='s1')
```

---

*Note: I've appended a faster method which works for int-like dtypes (like datetime64).*

We want to add a MultiIndex level of the [cumcounts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items) for each item, that way we trick the Index into becoming unique:

```
In [23]: s0.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
Out[23]:
0    0
0    1
1    0
dtype: int64
```

*Note: I can't seem to append a column to the index without being a DataFrame..*

```
In [24]: df0 = pd.DataFrame(s0).set_index(s0.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)

In [25]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(s1).set_index(s1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)

In [26]: df0
Out[26]:
     s0
0 0   1
  1   2
1 0   3
```

Now we can go ahead and concat these:

```
In [27]: res = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)

In [28]: res
Out[28]:
     s0  s1
0 0   1   1
  1   2 NaN
1 0   3   4
  1 NaN   5
```

If you want to drop the cumcount level:

```
In [29]: res.index = res.index.droplevel(1)

In [30]: res
Out[30]:
   s0  s1
0   1   1
0   2 NaN
1   3   4
1 NaN   5
```

*Now you can ffill to get the desired result... (if you were concerned about forward filling of different datetimes you could groupby the index and ffill).*

---

If the upperbound on repetitions in each group was reasonable (I'm picking 1000, but much  higher is still "reasonable"!, you could use a Float64Index as follows (and certainly it seems more elegant):

```
s0.index = s0.index + (s0.groupby(level=0)._cumcount_array() / 1000.)
s1.index = s1.index + (s1.groupby(level=0)._cumcount_array() / 1000.)
res = pd.concat([s0, s1], axis=1)
res.index = res.index.values.astype('int64')
```

*Note: I'm cheekily using a private method here which returns the cumcount as a numpy array...*
*Note2: This is pandas 0.14, in 0.13 you have to pass a numpy array to `_cumcount_array` e.g. `np.arange(len(s0))`), pre-0.13 you're out of luck - there's no cumcount.*

Comment: This works well.  I don't think I could have come up with this myself :-).  It's much more slower than a Cython program to do the same though.  I think the kind of merge I want is specific enough that I will have to do it in Cython if I want speed for big time series.  I learned quite a bit about Pandas from your post.  Thanks!

Comment: I think the expensive part is the resetting of index... Hmmm if you had an upper limit on the number in each group you could just add (cumcounts / X) to the index and that may be faster. In fact that could be easier.

Comment: @Alok-- see appended solution, it's also __much__ simpler and faster.

Comment: @Alok Note: you'd have wrap this with view/astype int before and DatetimeIndex after with your example.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks.  I was thinking of doing something similar (i.e. adding a fractional "count" to every unique index value), but I didn't even know where to begin.  I am getting an error in `_cumcount_array()` -- it seems to want an argument.  This could be due to me having an older pandas version?

Comment: @Alok cumcount is new in 0.13, and to be fair `_cumcount_array` is a private method (which, ahem, I wrote...) though I'm pretty sure it's been around from 0.13). It shouldn't require an argument (I ran the code above in 0.14).

Comment: I am using 0.13.1 and that method exists but needs a required `arr` argument.  Here's the traceback: `TypeError: _cumcount_array() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`. I need to do `.grouper._max_groupsize, dtype='int64')`, but then it seems to work.  Trying on real data now.

Comment: @Alok-- ok, I guess I made it optional to pass an output array in 0.14, so pass something like: `np.arange(len(s0))`...

Answer (score 1):

How about this - convert to dataframes with labeled columns first, then concat().

```
s1 = pd.Series(index=['4/4/14','4/4/14','4/5/14'],
                      data=[12.2,0.0,12.2])
s2 = pd.Series(index=['4/5/14','4/8/14'],
                      data=[14.2,3.0])
d1 = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['a'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(b,columns=['b'])

final_df = pd.merge(d1, d2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

This gives me

```
           a     b
4/4/14  12.2   NaN
4/4/14   0.0   NaN
4/5/14  12.2   14.2
4/8/14   NaN   3.0
```

Comment: I don't believe that does what I want.  It seems to concatenate the individual series sequentially, while I want a merge.  Please see my edited post for a better example.

Comment: So in your edited example, `final_df` would have 4 rows, with the values for `4/5/14` being `12.2` and `14.2`.  And the values for `4/8/14` would be `12.2` and `3.0` ("filled forward").

Comment: Thanks!  Almost there.  In your example, if both `d1` and `d2` had 2 values for `4/5/14`, I want `final_df` to also have two values for those dates (what `zip()` does in Python).  The above will give me `2*2=4` rows.  See the values for `2014-01-01 01:00:01` in my question for example.